# How to Convert XAML File (View) into DependencyObject?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am working on a project where i have to deal with navigation based on Frame in MVVM pattern thus to get to the element Name x:Name of type Frame we have to convert MainWindow into DependencyObject like this..

```
 private static FrameworkElement GetDescendantFromName(DependencyObject parent, string name)
        {
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

            if (count < 1)
            {
                return null;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var frameworkElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as FrameworkElement;
                if (frameworkElement != null)
                {
                    if (frameworkElement.Name == name)
                    {
                        return frameworkElement;
                    }

                    frameworkElement = GetDescendantFromName(frameworkElement, name);
                    if (frameworkElement != null)
                    {
                        return frameworkElement;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

In Navigation Service Class i use...

```
var frame = GetDescendantFromName(Application.Current.MainWindow, "FrameName") as Frame;
frame.source = new Uri("Views/StudentView.Xaml");
```

This technique is limited to only MainWindow. When i pass new instence of EmployeeDetailView.Xaml as a depenecy Object, The Xaml File is not loaded and GetChildrenCount() returns 0.

```
var frame = GetDescendantFromName(EmployeeDetaiView.Xaml, "FrameName") as Frame;
```

here frame has **null** value.
how could i make it work with currently rendered EmployeeDetailView to get the Frame element?

Comment: Pass the view instance as first parameter to your method? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: _"This technique is limited to only MainWindow"_ -- why? What makes you say that? If you have a reference to any other view, why can't you just pass that reference to the same method, to traverse that view's visual tree and retrieve the element of interest? More to the point, why do you have this method at all? Why don't you just call [`FrameworkElement.FindName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, along with a detailed and specific explanation of what that code does, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: @Clemens by doing so .GetChildrenCount always returns 0

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am using WPF navigation service as implemented by this article http://www.saramgsilva.com/index.php/2014/modern-ui-for-wpf-application-by-example-navigationservice-mvvm/
using MVVM light thus it only works in MainWindow not other views

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Application.LoadComponent Method (Uri)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596996(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Page p = (Page) Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("Views/EmployeeDetaiView.Xaml.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

var ctrl = GetDescendantFromName(p, "SomeControl");
```

Here, `EmployeeDetaiView.Xaml` lies in Views folder.

**EDIT #1 after user comments**

However, as pointed by OP in his comment that `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount()` is returning 0. This happens because `p` is not part of `VisualTree`, once it is part of `VisualTree` it will work correctly.

```
    Page p;
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        p = (Page) Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("Views/EmployeeDetaiView.Xaml.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        Frm.Content = p;

        // This will print 0
        int i = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(p);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count = " + i);
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Now it will correctly print 1, as 'p' is now part of VisualTree
        int i = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(p);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Children count = " + i);
    }
```

Comment: This solved the partial part but Problem presist that by doing this VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount( ) returns 0 :(